# Installation of erp next app using WSL in windows 11 systeme

Tags: erpnext, frappe

I've been following the setup instruction given in this link [Reference](https://discuss.frappe.io/t/guide-how-to-install-erpnext-v14-on-linux-ubuntu-step-by-step-instructions/92960). I tried the steps and installation was fine until 6.2.

Not able to see the site in localhost:8000. Can you suggest me any info that would very helpful.